# libmicrohttpd based server with out of band authentication

Tags: c, http, webserver

I'm trying to develop a very basic webserver on which every page is protected but authentication is completed over a separate socket connection/protocol.

I'm trying to use libmicrohttpd for this and the process I'm hoping to have in the end is:

1. Landing page is displayed on first connection
2. Requests for all linked pages generate an http 102 message (to avoid authentication request with http 403 message and timeout while processing authentication request)
3. Out-of-band authentication process initiated and operates independently of the webserver
4. When authentication process returns, send appropriate message based on result

I'm a little new to both libmicrohttpd and http dev at this level and I had thought I could just send a respsosne with the 102 status code

```
ret = MHD_queue_response (connection, MHD_HTTP_PROCESSING, response);
```

then later on just send the final response changing in the `MHD_HTTP_OK` in the same function call.  But, even if I put the two responses in the queue with no other processing in between (or with some arbitrary delay) the client never receives the second response and just times out eventually.

I'm wondering:

- Is there an http status code issue? Or is it consistent to send more responses after http 102, eventually http 200 or otherwise?
- Is there a different MHD function or options I should be using when I want to queue additional responses to the same client like this?
- Is there something special I should be doing with the daemon set up to support this?
- Or, of course, am I completely off-base that this could/should be done in this way?

For reference, my daemon is set up with the most basic of options (from the first tutorial example):

```
daemon = MHD_start_daemon (MHD_USE_SELECT_INTERNALLY, port, NULL, 
                NULL, &generate_page, NULL, MHD_OPTION_END);
```

If I just serve up html files in the responses, everything works otherwise.

Any and all advice is appreciated--even if it's to tell me where to go.

Comment: I know realize that my primary problem was that I was trying to re-use the same response in both calls to `MHD_queue_response `, even though nothing actually gets displayed on the client browser because of the http 102.  Thus, when I was trying to queue the actual response with http 200 MHD had already deleted the response I was trying to access.

I'm leaving the question open to see if anyone who reads  it has any advice or perspective on the other questions/points before I mark as answers/closed.

Answer (score 0):

Primary problem was that I was trying to re-use the same response in both calls to MHD_queue_response, even though nothing actually gets displayed on the client browser because of the http 102. Thus, when I was trying to queue the actual response with http 200 MHD had already deleted the response I was trying to access and this could have been resolved either by using a dummy response, or making the response persistent.